# Matching text with "or" function in Excel results in #VALUE! error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Apologies if this is the wrong forum for this question...

L30 has a nested if statement that results in the text "in".

L31 is the formula =L30=OR("in","hold") which results in a #VALUE! error.  I was hoping to get a TRUE from that.  Strangely enough, when I change the formula in L31 to =OR(EXACT(L30,"in"),EXACT(L30,"hold")), it evaluates to TRUE as expected.

I feel like there's probably something basic regarding strings or formulas that I'm just not understanding...

Comment: =OR(A2="in", A2="hold") might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) is a function in Excel which takes at least two conditions and returns `TRUE` if one of them evaluates to `TRUE`. Your formula `L30=OR("in","hold")` uses the two strings "in" and "hold" as conditions - which of course does not work as those are not logical conditions.
What you probably want is `=OR(L30="in", L30="hold")`

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt uses the wrong syntax for OR, and your second example uses the correct syntax.

```
=OR(L30="in",L30="hold")
```